# How should run a function 5 times in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically, I'm trying to create 5 rows of tables, using a loop function. I've already have the codes for creating one row. How do I run the script 5 times in jQuery ?

I don't quite understand how .each(); works to do a loop. Can somebody please explain to me? Thanks.

Comment: There isn't really a better explanation than the docs for [$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/). I don't want to close the question if there's something we can help you with, but before we can do that, can you explain where your problem is in understanding?

Comment: [Please don't be too lazy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/157574).

Answer (score 9):

```
for (var i=0; i<5; ++i ){
  doSomething();
}
```